# Flask application on Docker image appears to run fine when ran from Docker Desktop; unable to deploy on Ec2,"Essential container in task exited"

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, flask, amazon-ec2

I am currently trying to deploy a Docker image. The Docker image is of a Flask application; when I run the image via Docker desktop, the service works fine. However, after creating an EC2 instance on Amazon and running the image as a **task**, I get the error "Stopped reason Essential container in task exited".

I am unsure of how to trouble shoot or what steps to take. Do advice!

Edit:
I noticed that my Docker file on my computer is of 155mb while that on AWS is 67mb. Does AWS do any compression? I will be trying to push my image again.

Edit2:
Reading through some other qn, it appears that it is normal for file sizes to differ as the Docker desktop shows the uncompressed version.

I decided to run the AWS Task Image on my Docker desktop, while it does run and the console shows everything is fine, I am unable to access the links provided.

```
* Serving Flask app 'main' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
 * Running on http://172.17.0.2:5000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: XXXXXX
```

Under my Docker file, I have made sure to `EXPOSE 5000` already. I am unsure why after running the same image on Amazon on my local machine, I am unable to connect to it on my local machine.

```
FROM alpine:latest
ENV PATH /usr/local/bin:$PATH
RUN apk add --no-cache python3
RUN apk add py3-pip && pip3 install --upgrade pip
WORKDIR /backend
RUN pip3 install wheel
RUN pip3 install --extra-index-url https://alpine-wheels.github.io/index numpy
COPY . /backend 
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["main.py"]
```

Edit3:
I believe I "found" the problem but I am unsure how to run it. When I was building the Docker file, inside `VSCode` I would run it via doing `docker run -it -d -p 5000:5000  flaskapp` , where the tags `-d` and `-p 5000:5000` means running it in **demo** mode and **port forwarding** the 5000 port. When I run the image that way inside `VSCode`, I am able to access the application on my local machine.

However, after creating the image and running it via pressping `Start` inside `Docker Desktop`, I am unable to access it on my local machine.

How will I go about running the `Docker` image this way either via `Docker Desktop` or `Amazon EC2`?

Comment: I have included the following line in my `main.py` file actually. Inside the console, it does show` * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0) `. Is this not sufficient or? 
```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: Sorry, I believe I misread the output in your question.

Comment: Even after that, I am unable to access it via `localhost` on my own computer. It should allow me to right?